# How to customize css for ng-select in angular?

Tags: css, angular, angular-ngselect

I am trying to customize the css of ng-select using default view encapsulation. I am using ::ng-deep for this.

This section seems to work:

```
 .ng-select.custom-ng-select ::ng-deep {
          //this section works//
                 &.ng-select-container {
                        border: 1px solid #1CBC88;
                        color: #1CBC88 !important;
                        box-shadow: none;
                        font-size: 13px !important;
                        font-weight: bold;   }
```

However, the section below doesnot work:

```
                   &.ng-select-opened {
                    &.ng-select-bottom {
                        >.ng-select-container {
                            border-bottom: 1px solid red;
                        }
                    }
                   }
```

}

I want to change the bottom border color when the select is opened by using ::ng-deep selector on ng-select. Thanks.

Comment: see this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62782237/ng-select-style-group-headers-and-items/62782433#62782433 you can override style in `styles.css`

Answer (score 4):

Brother, you can add this CSS to your component.scss file

```
::ng-deep.ng-select-container {
        border-bottom: 1px solid red !important;
     }
```

And you can also add like this globally in styles.scss

```
.ng-select-container {
        border-bottom: 1px solid red !important;
     }
```